# Limit the number of documents in a collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that use as a cache. How can I limit the documents number to 5M inside this collection.
Note: that the cache item can be updated will existing in the cache.
I use tried to use capped, but the item saves in a capped collection cannot be modified.

Is there a way to do that?
(i would like to avoid delete the item and then insert the update one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's not much you can do here. As you noted, documents in capped collections can't be modified. And also, you can't specify a limit in documents, it's in megabytes, IIRC.

So, your best bet is to use normal collection and have a periodic job that'll check the collection for overflows and will clean up old documents.

Answer (score 1):

**db.createCollection("collectionName",{capped:true,size:10000,max:1000})**

this command is used to create fixed size collection where

*collectionName* : name of collection on whicg you want to put limit 
*capped: true* (fixed size collection)
*size*: maximum size of collection in bytes
*max*: limit to the no. of documents

Answer (score 0):

Though this might be a little too late, with 3.x MongoDB this is possible using something on lines of [CreateCollectionOptions](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/client/model/CreateCollectionOptions.html).

A sample code in *Java* to do so would be:

```
mongoClient.getDatabase(databaseName).createCollection(collectionName, 
    new CreateCollectionOptions().capped(true).sizeInBytes(5120).maxDocuments(100));
```

where 5120 is the size in bytes for 5MB and 100 is an upper limit of the number of documents you can store in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to delete documents in a collection when a limit reached in mongodb

For that I created nodejs process that will do the job

[Documented in my GitHub page](https://github.com/0-kodiya-0/MongoCollectionLimiter)

I hope this will help and this my first git repo